# Keychain prompt - Switch to other window via keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keychain

Whenever the Keychain prompt pops up, the window has the focus, and I haven't found a way to switch away from it via the keyboard. I know entering my password dismisses the window, but sometimes I'm just browsing the web, and Mail.app will trigger that window, forcing me to change focus.

Is there any way to switch out of that window via the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid as a security precaution it is not allowed to be switched away from the password prompt. Otherwise malicious apps will be given chance to record your inputs.

Comment: Makes a good explanation :)